# Mail sent to a .herokuapp.com domain

Tags: heroku, mailgun

I would like to configure Heroku and Mailgun to send email from and allow me to receive webhooks (which are POSTs Mailgun sends notifying me of email sending statuses) at a [myapp.]herokuapp.com domain while buying as few additional things as possible. I don't want to buy another domain name, but it doesn't appear that I can avoid that. I'd like to avoid buying another SSL endpoint; it doesn't appear to be necessary and I don't need privacy. What do I need to buy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cheapest way to do what you want is to use a custom domain name, add it to Heroku, then verify your domain with mailgun.

You can add custom domains to your Heroku app by running: `heroku domains:add www.mydomain.com`

Once you've done this (and updated your DNS provider to point to `yourapp.herokuapp.com`, you can then modify your DNS records for Mailgun to verify your domain.

Once you have that working, you should be good!

Since you can't modify Heroku's DNS servers, you need to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a subquestion as the answer.

Just to send emails, I think you can

- have Free plan and send to allowed (max 5) recipients,
- have Concept plan and send to all recipients; you must enter credit card but you can limit count of messages to 10000/month which is free. For this you will need your domain, however, when you will use a subdomain like myheroku.example.com in TXT DNS-entries, then you can use such domain for any other goals (ie send from more servers, point to other IP or so).

Could somebody confirm this? or make it more clear...